# Any Easy to extend Web-based File Manager for node.js?

Tags: node.js, file-manager

Want to find one and modify that to read, write file on mongoDB gridfs store

Comment: Did you ever find out anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Nodepad:

This tutorial will give you a good idea on how it was made: http://dailyjs.com/2010/11/01/node-tutorial/ As knowing how it was made it should make it heaps easer to extend it. :) It is quite basic, I'm re-writing the whole thing myself :P

Nodepad on github: https://github.com/alexyoung/nodepad

It even uses MongoDB, I'm going to do the opposite to what you wanted to do and that is make it not use MongoDB. :P

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Cloud Commander](http://cloudcmd.io) node.js-based orthodox file manager. It could be used as middleware for [express](http://expressjs.com) this way:

```js
var http        = require('http'),
    cloudcmd    = require('cloudcmd'),
    express     = require('express'),
    io          = require('socket.io'),
    app         = express(),

    PORT        = 1337,

    server,
    socket;

server = http.createServer(app);
socket = io.listen(server);

app.use(cloudcmd({
    socket: socket,     /* used by Config, Edit (optional) and Console (required)   */
    config: {           /* config data (optional)                                   */
        prefix: '/cloudcmd', /* base URL or function which returns base URL (optional)   */
    }
}));

server.listen(PORT);
```

When you need a file tree you could try this [angular/node based example](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/file-browser-with-jstree-angularjs-and-expressjs/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/OpusCapita/filemanager

It has a NodeJS server implementation and react client implementation.

Can be easily extended using "connectors"