# CDN server written in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to find an example of a CDN server written in nodejs that does the following:

- Minification of CSS & JS
- Pre-Compiling LESS
- Pre-Compiling CoffeeScript
- Static Redirection if content already available in another bucket
- A management interface

I realize that something like this already exists (S3 etc) but my interest is academic. I am interested if something like this has been done in node, and how.

Comment: i found this: https://github.com/niftylettuce/express-cdn - not exactly what i want, since it needs s3 but useful.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at [express-cdn](https://github.com/niftylettuce/express-cdn), a module to deliver compressed, minified and assets combined assets to CDN servers (Currently Amazon S3). It lacks some management interface but implements a couple of features you require.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [grunt](http://weblog.bocoup.com/introducing-grunt/), it has plugins for every kind of asset pipeline.

Comment: Grunt is a build tool, not a CDN server.

Answer (score 0):

I cant find a module to perform all your tasks at the same time. You should mix modules in your application. I recommend you look at [npmjs.org](https://npmjs.org)

Minification of CSS & JS ---> [Here](https://npmjs.org/search?q=minify)

Pre-Compiling LESS ---> [Here](http://onedayitwillmake.com/blog/2013/03/compiling-less-from-a-node-js-script/)

Pre-compiling CoffeScript (The command-line version of coffee is available as a Node.js utility.) [Here](http://coffeescript.org/)

Static Redirection if content already available in another bucket: Nothing clear, you should have some kind of db for the files, for the redirections go to [nginx.org](http://nginx.org/en/docs/) <3

A management interface: [Any Easy to extend Web-based File Manager for node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869960/any-easy-to-extend-web-based-file-manager-for-node-js)